# Flutter is it possible to reduce the size of the numpad and put an up and down key into numpad?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on flutter app and in that app I have many cells(text fields) to enter data(only numbers with decimal exp. 1.0, 2.5, 5.3 etc). The problem is that the default keyboard is too big. I want to reduce the size of the numpad. Numpad also have up, down and next keys to move the cursor up, down and forward. Is there any library for this? Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the size of numpad.

But you create your own keyboard which shows up onFocus of Textfield. You can check this pub to add shortcuts above keyboard: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions